# Questions regarding migration of existing content to RBS

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server, rbs

How much time does it take to migrate existing data into RBS? I am talking about `$rbs.Migrate()` command.

For e.g. if I want to migrate 1GB of data, surely it will take time. But question is how much? I know it depends but still I just want to get an idea like a few hours or 1 day etc?

Secondly, while this migration is being done can I still use SharePoint and upload documents in library?

Thirdly, is there a progress report which shows how much data has been migrated? For e.g. some kind of progress bar showing percentage complete? How will I know once migration is complete?